# How can I make an NSTextField containing attributed text but only copy plain text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

I have an `NSTextField` subclass which uses a `NSTextFieldCell` subclass which contains an attributed string. I would like it if when the user copies text that it be copied to the pasteboard without the attributes.

I have tried subclassing `NSTextView`, overriding `copy:` and setting `isFieldEditor` to `YES` and returning this new editor from the cells `fieldEditorForView` method. While this copies only the plain text whenever it is used I have text drawn on text drawn on text (and so on ...) and if the underlying attributed string is changed by another control the field editor remains unmodified. When I do not use `MyFieldEditor` and let the `NSTextFieldCell` subclass use the default implementation this issue does not occur.

Is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Is there something additional that I need to override or receive delegate messages for?

## `MyFieldCell.m`

```
- (NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    MyFieldEditor *editor = [[MyFieldEditor alloc] init];
    [super setUpFieldEditorAttributes:editor];

    return editor;
}
```

## `MyFieldEditor.m`

```
@implementation MyFieldEditor

- (instancetype)init
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) )
    {
        [self setFieldEditor:YES];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *)selectedString
{
    return [[self string] substringWithRange:[self selectedRange]];
}

- (void)copy:(id)sender
{
    [[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:[self selectedString] forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
}

@end
```

Note: I am using ARC.

## Display Issue Image

[image: Drawing problem]

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of turning an NSAtrributedString object into a plain text string object?

Comment: It looks like a bug, I don't see any issues on macOS 10.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below what should be changed. **Tested & works with Xcode 11.2.1 / macOS 10.15.2 with no display issues.**

a) No custom `NSTextFieldCell` and `NSTextField` are needed, so used just default

b) Change to following in `MyFieldEditor.m`

```
- (void)copy:(id)sender
{
    [NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard declareTypes:@[NSPasteboardTypeString] owner:self];
    [NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard setString:[self selectedString] forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
}
```

c) Add window delegate method substituting field editor for targeted textfield (this is the valid documented way to provide custom field editors)

```
- (nullable id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(nullable id)client {
    if (client == self.textField) { // << in this case it is outlet
        return MyFieldEditor.new;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Update:**

Overriding NSTextFieldCell as below and assigning it in XIB for targeted NSTextField instead of above NSWindow delegate method gives the same valid behaviour.

```
@interface MyTextCell: NSTextFieldCell
@end

@implementation MyTextCell
- (nullable NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:(NSView *)controlView {
    id editor = MyFieldEditor.new;
    [super setUpFieldEditorAttributes:editor];
    return editor;
}
@end
```

Comment: Is `-[NSCell fieldEditorForView:]` not a valid documented way to provide custom field editors?

Comment: @Willeke, it appears using `[NSCell fieldEditorForView:]` is alternate path (both are used by `[NSWindow fieldEditor:forObject:]`. As I tested in my env both alternates work the same, overriding cell just require more steps. Probably topic started has some other issues as well setting up NSCell-based path.

Comment: While this works for copy pasting if via a second control (In my case a Slider) the text is changed the field editor is not updated nor is it removed with an `abortEditing`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `fieldEditorForView:` is called repeatedly. Every time it's called it creates a new `MyFieldEditor` and doesn't get rid of the old field editor.

An `NSWindow` has only one field editor which it reuses. I guess the assumption is that any field editor of a given type should only ever be created once and should be reused. As such a static variable referencing the editor and a `nil` check to create provides a lazy reusable editor.

```
@interface MyFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell
@end

@implementation MyFieldCell
- (nullable NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    static MyFieldEditor *kEditor;

    if ( kEditor ) { return kEditor; }
    kEditor = [[MyFieldEditor alloc] init];

    return kEditor;
}
@end
```

It would be nice if the editor could be made weak though. Unfortunately `NSTextView` and its subclasses are incompatible with weak references. If anyone has a cleaver idea around this I am all ears.

Comment: `NSTextView` does support weak references since 10.12.

Comment: My app provides support for 10.11 and later. I guess thats why I get the warning.